# How do I test for TempData being set in MVC 2 where there is a redirect?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

When trying to test my MVC 2 controllers, I am having a hard time testing the result of `TempData` when I'm doing a redirect.  It works ok if the result of the controller action is a `ViewResult`, however, in a redirect, it is `RedirectToRouteResult`.

So my test is something like this:

```
var controller = new SubscriptionController(this.dataStorageMock.Object)
    {
        ControllerContext = MvcMockHelpers.GetControllerContextMock("POST")
    };

var actionResult = controller.Create(formCollection);
var redirectResult = (RedirectToRouteResult)actionResult;

// TODO: Need to ensure TempData contains a key "info".
```

One option is to do the following:

```
Assert.That(controller.TempData.ContainsKey("info"));
```

If the result had been a `ViewResult` it could have been tested like this:

```
var viewResult = (ViewResult)actionResult;
Assert.That(viewResult.TempData.ContainsKey("info"));
```

Is there a way to test `RedirectToRouteResult` the same way as the `ViewResult` can be tested?

Thanks

Answer (score 34):

`Assert.That(controller.TempData.ContainsKey("info"));` is exactly what you need.

Comment: I was hoping for a way to see the resulting effect (like ‘ViewResult‘) instead of the set property. If there isn't a way, then I guess there's not a way.

Comment: controller.TempData["info"].